# TAR.GZ file shows in 'git status' after tar.gz

Tags: python, git, gzip, tar

Working in git/Python...

**Background:**

I have a python script that is uncompressing content, that must be versioned, reading that content and the re-compressing that content to save space. Every day when my 'over-night' script runs it shows that all of the the ".tar.gz" file has changed even though I have checked the contents and found in many of the .tar.gz files nothing has changed.

*~~ Edit Start ~~*

*I have checked the MD5sum of the each file along the way, each of the contents of the "tar", the md5 of the 'tar', and the md5 of the 'gz' and found, it seems that the md5's of each layer are a perfect match, the only thing changing may be the meta data on the file itself, things like date/timestamp*

*~~ Edit End ~~*

**Question:**

I'm looking for some help or information concerning maybe the fact that I should only GZ the files, that 'tar' is adding a hash that is changing even though the content inside the 'tar' is the same.

-- OR --

How to make git ignore the hash of the .tar.gz without adding it to the .gitignore file, since the content in these files may change and would then need to be updated in the git repo.

Comment: If you are in fact able to "save space", then of course the files are different.

Comment: The correct solution is not to use git to store tarballs.

Comment: In general, Git is very bad at storing large *compressed* files (and tar.gz files are compressed and are usually quite large as well). It's usually not that great at storing large non-text files either (tar files falling into this category). A tar archive is a snapshot; a commit contains a snapshot; so in general instead of a tar or tar.gz you'd *extract* the tarball, and that's what you'd store in Git as a commit.

Comment: gzip itself can magnify changes, because the content in your file changes the compression table used to compress future content. This is why such a thing as "rsyncable gzip" exists. Using `git` for this purpose is a very bad choice of tools -- if you want to store large files/directories in an efficient way and differentially download changes, consider [`desync`](https://github.com/folbricht/desync), which is a reimplementation of [`casync`](http://0pointer.net/blog/casync-a-tool-for-distributing-file-system-images.html); casync is designed-to-purpose for storing system images.

Comment: (what "rsyncable gzip" does is reset the gzip compression table to prevent changes in the file from cascading as far; but if you're using a tool like git that compresses things anyhow, then compressing content _before_ giving it to git is a bad idea in the first place -- you're making the total storage worse, not better, by doing that, because you prevent git from calculating efficient diffs; and you'd get the benefit of those diffs being stored compressed no matter what)

Comment: ...if there's any lesson I'd hope you would take from my comments above, it's that it's easy to invent a suboptimal solution if you don't know what your tools are doing under the hood, and that there's a lot of prior art and research already in existence that _has_ resulted in significantly closer-to-optimal approaches; if your tarballs are big enough to justify the tools, using git to build a history of .caibx or .caidx files and keeping the chunks being referred to in S3 or another non-git blob store is probably a lot closer to optimal than where you are now).

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy I will continue doing reading on this, all history will be kept in this question for anyone that has the same question hopefully they'll find the correct path for their needs.

Comment: I was able to see the amount of changes brought in so ended up using a global that keeps track of the change and can be referenced across all functions easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much consideration I have decided to do a comparison on the old and new file to ensure that the new file is only used once it's confirmed that the files are in fact different. I'm working to test this more fully but think that this may "fix" the issue.

```
def cleanPath(path):
    path = path.replace('/','\\')
    return path

def untar(tar_path):
    print(f'Trying to unzip... {tar_path}')
    try:
        tar_path = cleanPath(tar_path)
        # path_date = tar_path.split("\\")[-1].replace(".tar.gz","")
        path_date = tar_path.replace('.tar.gz','')
        print(path_date)
        # open file
        file = tarfile.open(tar_path)
    
        # extracting file
        file.extractall(path_date)
      
        file.close()
    except Exception as ex:
        print("Unzip Failure")
        print(ex)
        return False
    return True

def tar(tar_path):
    print(f'Trying to zip...{tar_path}')
    # TAR the file
    try:
        print("tar_path")
        print(tar_path)
        old_file_path = f"{tar_path}_new.tar.gz"
        tar_file = f"{tar_path}_new.tar.gz"
        with tarfile.open(tar_file,'w:gz') as tar_handle:
            for r,d,f in os.walk(tar_path):
                for gz_file in f:
                    # tar_handle.add(file)
                    tar_handle.add(os.path.join(r,gz_file),gz_file)
        try:
            shutil.rmtree(tar_path)
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)
    except Exception as ex:
        print("Zip Failure")
        print(ex)
        return False
    # Check the MD5 of each side, leave the old file if possible
    try:
        old_hash = hashlib.md5(open(old_file_path,'rb').read()).hexdigest()
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
    try:
        new_hash = hashlib.md5(open(tar_file,'rb').read()).hexdigest()
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)

    if new_hash == old_hash:
        # leave the old file
        os.remove(tar_file)
    else:
        # remove the old file
        try:
            os.remove(old_file_path)
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)
        # rename the new file to the old file name
        os.rename(tar_file,old_file_path)
    return True
```

Comment: Side note: md5 is sort of OK for comparing files, but SHA hashes are better (though more computationally intensive). Consider also variants of [BLAKE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLAKE_(hash_function)).

Comment: Aren't the two files on the same system? You have to read all of both old and new to compute a signature like an MD5. You can just as well, actually better, directly compare the two files. There is no need for signatures.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload then on a specific folder, and ignore all the contents of the given folder.

like:

.gitignore

```
 /files/*
```

Comment: I'm sorry I'm looking to not use a .gitignore as the content of these files may change or may need to change. I'm thinking that "tar" or "gz" is adding something that git is picking up even though the contents has remained unchanged.

Comment: Oh yeah, *.tar is different from *.gz. If u change the filename git considers as a hole new file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).